# Alarm.alarmRepeat repeats only twice then stops working

Tags: arduino, embedded

I'm using an arduino uno with a CC3000 WiFi Shield. The ardunio counts people using a light barrier and then reports the countings to the xievly site. It seems to work fine for an hour or two but then nothing happens. Any ideas?

```
// Libraries
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Time.h>
#include <TimeAlarms.h>

// Define CC3000 chip pins
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ   3
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT  5
#define ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS    10

// Create CC3000 instances
Adafruit_CC3000 cc3000 = Adafruit_CC3000(ADAFRUIT_CC3000_CS, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_IRQ, ADAFRUIT_CC3000_VBAT,
                                         SPI_CLOCK_DIV2); // you can change this clock speed                                         
// WLAN parameters
#define WLAN_SSID       "XX"
#define WLAN_PASS       "XX"
#define WLAN_SECURITY   WLAN_SEC_WPA2

// Xively parameters
#define WEBSITE  "https://xively.com/feeds/XX"
#define API_key  "XXX"
#define feedID  "XXXX``"

uint32_t ip;
Adafruit_CC3000_Client client;

const unsigned long
  connectTimeout  = 15L * 1000L, // Max time to wait for server connection
  responseTimeout = 15L * 1000L; // Max time to wait for data from server

// Visitor Counter
int anzahl =0;
int lastState=LOW;
const int inputPin = 2;


void setup()
{
  // Initialize
  attachInterrupt(0, count, RISING);
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!cc3000.begin())
  {
    while(1);
  }
    // Connect to WiFi network
  cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY);

  /* Wait for DHCP to complete */
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(100);
  }  
  unsigned long t  = getTime();
  cc3000.disconnect();
  setTime(hour(t)+2,minute(t),second(t),month(t),day(t),year(t));
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(9,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(10,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(11,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(12,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(13,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(14,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(15,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(16,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(17,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(18,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(19,59,59, Messung);
  Alarm.alarmRepeat(22,59,59, Zeitkorrektur);
}

void count()
{
  delay(10);
  int val = digitalRead(inputPin);
  if (val == HIGH && lastState==LOW)
{
    anzahl++;
    lastState=val;
  }
  else
  {
    lastState=val;
  }
}

void Zeitkorrektur()
{
  getTime();
}

void Messung()
{
  datalog();
}

void loop()
{
  Alarm.delay(1000);
}

// Minimalist time server query; adapted from Adafruit Gutenbird sketch,
// which in turn has roots in Arduino UdpNTPClient tutorial.
unsigned long getTime() 
{
  uint8_t       buf[48];
  unsigned long ip, startTime, t = 0L;

  // Hostname to IP lookup; use NTP pool (rotates through servers)
  if(cc3000.getHostByName("pool.ntp.org", &ip)) {
    static const char PROGMEM
      timeReqA[] = { 227,  0,  6, 236 },
      timeReqB[] = {  49, 78, 49,  52 };

    Serial.println(F("\r\nAttempting connection..."));
    startTime = millis();
    do {
      client = cc3000.connectUDP(ip, 123);
    } while((!client.connected()) &&
            ((millis() - startTime) < connectTimeout));

    if(client.connected()) {
      Serial.print(F("connected!\r\nIssuing request..."));

      // Assemble and issue request packet
      memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
      memcpy_P( buf    , timeReqA, sizeof(timeReqA));
      memcpy_P(&buf[12], timeReqB, sizeof(timeReqB));
      client.write(buf, sizeof(buf));

      Serial.print(F("\r\nAwaiting response..."));
      memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
      startTime = millis();
      while((!client.available()) &&
            ((millis() - startTime) < responseTimeout));
      if(client.available()) {
        client.read(buf, sizeof(buf));
        t = (((unsigned long)buf[40] << 24) |
             ((unsigned long)buf[41] << 16) |
             ((unsigned long)buf[42] <<  8) |
              (unsigned long)buf[43]) - 2208988800UL;
        Serial.print(F("OK\r\n"));
      }
      client.close();
    }
  }
  if(!t) Serial.println(F("error"));
  return t;
}

void datalog()
{
  //noInterrupts();
  // Connect to WiFi network
  cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY);

  /* Wait for DHCP to complete */
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP())
  {
    delay(100);
  }  

  // Set the website IP
  uint32_t ip = cc3000.IP2U32(216,52,233,120);
  cc3000.printIPdotsRev(ip);

  // Get data & transform to integers
  int visitors = (int) anzahl/2; //Visitors going in and out therefore divided by 2

  // Prepare JSON for Xively & get length
  int length = 0;

  String data = "";

  data = data + "\n" + "{\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"datastreams\" : [ {\"id\" : \"Visitors\",\"current_value\" : \"" + String(visitors) + "\"}]}";

  length = data.length();

  // Send request
  Adafruit_CC3000_Client client = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, 80);
  if (client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connected!");
    client.println("PUT /v2/feeds/" + String(feedID) + ".json HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: api.xively.com");
    client.println("X-ApiKey: " + String(API_key));
    client.println("Content-Length: " + String(length));
    client.print("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    client.print(data);
    client.println();
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));    
    return;
  }

  Serial.println(F("-------------------------------------"));
  while (client.connected()) {
    while (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.print(c);
    }
  }
  client.close();
  Serial.println(F("-------------------------------------"));

  Serial.println(F("\n\nDisconnecting"));
  cc3000.disconnect();
  anzahl =0;
  //interrupts();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In **setup()** you configured interrupt with **RISING**. That means that it fires when the pin goes from low state to high state. But in interrupt handler - count() you have strange logic which looks excessive since you already configured interrupt to fire only once on event.

Let's see what happens in **count()**. **val** will always be HIGH (well, considering only normal case, not glitches).. When the first interrupt comes **lastState** is LOW as initial value and we increment, but all successive calls will not because **lastState** is HIGH and never becomes LOW again.

So, to fix problem, we simply need to drop **lastState** because it's not needed

```
void count()
{
  delay(10);
  // avoiding glitches - check if it's still high
  int val = digitalRead(inputPin);
  if (val == HIGH)
    anzahl++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks pmod, you are right of course. I used the "strange logic" to avoid bouncing and forgot all about it when I started with the interrupt routine. I have now a Hardware solution for the bouncing problem and a simple void Count () routine.